# Reporting Services - Export Data to Excel In Only One Sheet

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I'm using SSRS 2005. In my report, I'm getting data to a table with paging(use with grouping). It's ok. But when I export data to Excel file, RS divide data within multiple sheet.

How can I get data in only one sheet while exporting to Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Write the following expression to disable the page-break during export to excel :-

```
IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Perfect solution!! Not sure why it hasn't been acknowledged yet.

Comment: For SSRS 2012, this option has to be set as follows:  RowGroups -> Groups -> Properties -> Page Break -> Disabled and then add the following expression =IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML", True, False)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do paging with using page breaks and also want to disable paging on excel, follow these steps;

1. Go to Tablix Member properties
2. PageBreak -> BreakLocation : `End`
3. PageBreak -> Disabled : `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="EXCELOPENXML",True, IIF(rownumber(nothing) mod 50=0, false, true))`

   [image]

Comment: Perfect Solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. Remove the page breaks, or live with it.

Comment: But when I remove page breaks, grouping cannot perform paging.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/ssrs-rendering-extensions/aspose.cells-for-reporting-services/default.aspx), a commercial rendering extension engine for SSRS.  We've used it for exporting reports to Word with Korean characters and it works great.  They provide good support as well.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCELOPENXML", True, IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) mod 30=0,False,True))
```

It does page break after 30 rows and disables page breaks when report is getting exported to Excel!